# Python replace() \r with \\r

Tags: python, arduino

i have this function written in Python, but i dont understand the replace method in here

```
def debugmsg(msgtext):
    msgtext = msgtext.replace('\r','\\r')
    msgtext = msgtext.replace('\n','\\n')
    print msgtext
```

can someone explain to me what's the meaning of replacing `\r` with `\\r` or `\n` with `\\n`? and how can I integrate this in arduino?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character `'\'` is used to give a special meaning to the next character. For example, `'\n'` is interpreted as the newline character in many systems, and `'\r'` also has a special meaning (carriage return). However when you want to write the character `'\'` itself, you need to escape it by writing `'\\'`, so that it does not give a special meaning to the next character. Thus, when you want to write the characters `'\'` and `'n'` in your text, you have to write it as `'\\n'` so that it is not understood as the special character `'\n'`.